# What's the intuition of the transpose of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, intuition, symmetry

I know the transpose is to swap the columns and rows of a matrix. And $A^T$$A$ is a symmetric matrix which elements are the inner product of each column of $A$. But I didn't understand the intuition of transpose. Suppose $A_{m \times n}$, and A transform a vector from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R^m$. But $A^T$ transform a vector from $\Bbb R^m$ to $\Bbb R^n$. What's the relationship between them? Could anyone please explain the relationship between $A^T$,$A$,the inner product and symmetric matrix. I think there would be a intuition explaination.

Comment: See: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37398/what-is-the-geometric-interpretation-of-the-transpose

Comment: See also:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/484844/intuition-behind-definition-of-transpose-map

Comment: This is critical to understand why the Rank and Determinant of $A^T$ are the same as $A$. Singular Value Decomposition is a good start.

Answer (score 3):

Well, $A^T$ is the *adjoint* matrix of $A$ with respect to the ordinary inner products, i.e. $A^T$ is the only linear mapping $B$ such that
$$\langle Av,w\rangle = \langle v,Bw\rangle$$
for all $v\in\Bbb R^n$ and $w\in\Bbb R^m$. You can easily see it if you verify it on the standard bases, noting that $\langle u,e_i\rangle$ gives the $i$th coordinate of $u$.

Comment: thank you. But how to use this conclusion? Is there any geometry explaination?

Comment: Real case: $\langle Av, w \rangle = (Av)^\top w = v^\top A^\top w = \langle v, A^\top w \rangle$ Complex case: $\langle Av, w \rangle = (Av)^\top \overline{w} = v^\top A^\top \overline{w} = v^\top \overline{A^* w} = \langle v, A^* w \rangle$

Answer (score 0):

One aspect of this to consider is that the transpose lets you do the same thing in different ways. The regular matrix gets multiplied by a column on the right to give your answer as a column. The transpose gets multiplied by a row on the left to give a row as the answer.

Is one better than the other? Not really, they're equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Good geometric ilustration of transpose is if we take as linear operator rotation matrix ***R***.
In this case is easy to see that < ***Rv***, ***w***> = < ***v***, $R^T$ ***w***> as we have 2 opportunities to change an angle between vector ***v*** and ***w*** to the same value.
One opportunity is to rotate ***v*** what   ***Rv*** operation does, the second one to rotate ***w*** in reverse direction what $R^T$  does ( transpose of ***R*** is inverse of ***R***).

Comment: That's the geometric intuition of an inverse matrix, not of the transpose ; you took the case where $R^{\top} = R^{-1}$, which is called an orthogonal matrix.

Comment: Yes, but in this case transpose is equal to inverse, I agree .. it is a special case.

Comment: I'm doing the comment because I myself do not have much intuition about the transpose... the answer didn't help me!

Comment: Maybe some additional intuition about transpose can be taken from decomposition of any matrix $A$ into symmetric and skew-symmetric part. In this case transpose gives the same symmetric part and skew-symmetric with minus sign.