# Intuition: Example of a transpose matrix representing a dual map

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, intuition

I'm reading Axler's **Linear Algebra Done Right** and trying to understand
exactly what the transpose of a matrix represents. To get some intuition, I
constructed the following example:

Let's say we're working with the two vector spaces $\mathbb{R}^3$ and
$\mathbb{R}^2$.

We have the linear map $T$:
$$ T : \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$$
$$ T(x,y,z) = (2x + 3y, 4z) $$

We also have the linear functional $\phi$:
$$ \phi : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$
$$ \phi(x,y) = (x + y) $$

We can compose these together:

$$ \phi \circ T : \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $$
$$ [\phi \circ T](x,y,z) = (2x + 3y - 4z) $$

We can also represent $T$ and $\phi$ with matrices:

$$ \mathcal{M}(T) = \left( \begin{array} & 2 & 3 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -4 \end{array} \right) $$
$$ \mathcal{M}(\phi) = \left( \begin{array} & 1 & 1 \end{array} \right)$$

So the matrix representation of $\phi \circ T$ is:

$$\mathcal{M}(\phi)\mathcal{M}(T) = \left( \begin{array} & 2 & 3 & -4 \end{array} \right) $$

The dual space of $\mathbb{R}^3$, $\mathbb{R}^{3\prime}$, is the set of linear
functionals $\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and likewise for
$\mathbb{R}^2$

Now, let $T\prime$ be the dual map of $T$:

$$
T^\prime : \mathbb{R}^{2\prime} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3\prime}
$$
$$
T^\prime(\phi) = \phi \circ T
$$

So $T^\prime$ is a "higher-order function" that maps one type of linear
functionals to another type of linear functional.

Supposedly, the matrix representation of $T^\prime$ is $\mathcal{M}(T)^T$, so

$$\mathcal{M}(T^\prime) = 
\left(
\begin{array}
& 2 & 0 \\
  3 & 0 \\
  0 & -4
\end{array}
\right)
$$

If everything is correct so far, the question I have is how to get from this
matrix to $ \left( \begin{array} & 2 & 3 & -4 \end{array} \right)$, which I
would expect to, again, be the final result. I would have expected that I could
simply multiply $\mathcal{M}(T^\prime)$ by $\mathcal{M}(\phi)$, since $\phi$ is
already an element of $\mathbb{R}^{2\prime}$, but that matrix is 1x2. So it seems
I would have to take its transpose as well, multiply it to the right of
$T^\prime$ to get a 3x1 matrix, and then transpose that to get the expected 1x3
matrix.

I'm guessing this is related to the algebraic property of dual maps that

$$ (ST)^\prime = T^\prime S^\prime $$

for all linear maps $S$ and $T$, but I don't understand why.

Related:
[Intuition behind definition of transpose map](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/484844/intuition-behind-definition-of-transpose-map)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do$$\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\3&0\\0&-4\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2\\3\\-4\end{pmatrix}.$$That's because the coordinates of $\phi$ in the dual of the canonical base are $1$ and $1$, that is, if the canonical basis is $(e_1,e_2)$, then $\phi={e_1}^*+{e_2}^*$.

Comment: I don't doubt that this is correct, but I don't understand it. Would you mind expanding on it? If not, I will just mark as answered.

Comment: @user2987808 The matrix of $T'$ with respect to the dual of the canonical basis is $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}2&0\\3&0\\0&-4\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ and both coordinates of $\phi$ in that basis are equal to $1$. Therefore the coordinates of $T'(\phi)$ are given by the product $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}2&0\\3&0\\0&-4\end{smallmatrix}\right)\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1\\1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$. So, the coordinates are $2$, $3$, and$-4$, as you wanted them to be.