# Why are the ordered singular values of $A^{−1}$ given by $\sigma _n^{ - 1} \ge ..... \ge \sigma _1^{ - 1}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, svd

Let $A\in{M_n}$ be nonsingular, with ordered singular values $\sigma _n^{} \le ..... \le \sigma _1^{}$. Is it true that the ordered singular values of $A^{−1}$ are $\sigma _n^{ - 1} \ge ..... \ge \sigma _1^{ - 1}$?

Comment: If $A=USV^*$, $A^{-1}=\ldots$

Answer (score 1):

I'm following the idea of Algebraic Pavel that gave you the hint. There's a result from linear Algebra (called [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition)) that tells you that you can decompose any non-singular matrix $A$ into a product
$$A = U\Sigma V,$$
where $U$ and $V$ are unitary, and $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix, with entries exactly the singular values $\sigma_i$, $i=1\dots n$.

Now clearly $A^{-1}=V^{-1}\Sigma^{-1}U^{-1}$, since $$U\Sigma VV^{-1}\Sigma^{-1}U^{-1}=I,$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix.

Your result follows from the properties of a diagonal matrix and the [uniqueness of the SVD](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/644327/how-unique-on-non-unique-are-u-and-v-in-singular-value-decomposition-svd). Indeed, $\Sigma^{-1}$ is again diagonal, with diagonal values $\sigma_i^{-1}$, $i=1,\dots n$ (an easy to show property of [diagonal matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_matrix#Matrix_operations)).