# Can any pair of SVD matrices diagonalize other matrices which share at least one pair of SVD matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

The title might require a little explanation. Given a complex matrix $Q\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ it has a singular value decomposition $Q=UD_QV^T$ with unitary matrices $U$ and $V$ and real, positive definit diagonal $D_Q$.

Let's say we have the SVD another matrix $Q'=WD_{Q'}X^T$  and we know that for *some* unitary matrices $A$ and $B$ both $A^H Q B^*$ and $A^H Q' B^*$ (where $^H$ is hermitian conjugation and $^*$ is complex conjugation, so that $A^H Q B^*=D_Q$) are diagonal with only positive entries on the diagonal. That is, there exist matrices which simultaneously decompose $Q$ and $Q'$ into singular values.

We know, that the SVD is in general [not unique](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/644327). My question is, whether it is possible to make some statements about the product $U^H Q' V^*$. Will this necessarily also be a diagonal matrix?

Comment: Here's a relevant fact: given to matrices $P,Q$ of the same shape, there exist unitary matrices $A,B$ such that both $APB$ and $AQB$ are real and diagonal if and only if both $PQ^*$ and $Q^*P$ are Hermitian. I'm not sure about a reference and I don't have a proof off the top of my head, but the fact is used in [this paper](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~dattorro/eckart&young.1936.pdf) for instance.

Comment: In general, we can't guarantee that $U^HQ'V^*$ will have any special structure. A counterexample exists with $n = 2$ and $Q = I$ (the identity matrix). I suspect, however, that if $Q$ has no repeating singular values, then $U^HQ'V^*$ can be guaranteed to be diagonal.