# Geometric interpretation of the adjoint - what does it mean that the graphs are orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I am trying to understand the adjoint of a linear operator geometrically. Since the graph of the adjoint can be constructed as the orthogonal complement of a "rotated" copy of the graph of the operator itself (details follow) I am wondering how orthogonality of the graphs translates to algebraic or topological relations between two operators.

What I mean by the above introductory remarks is that using the "rotation"
$$U\colon H\oplus H\to H\oplus H, \qquad (x,y)\mapsto (-y,x)$$ we can get the relation $$\mathrm{Graph}(A^*) = U(\mathrm{Graph}(A))^\perp.$$

This question is similar to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/37398/296126) but since I am also interested in the infinte dimensional case I would like to avoid the singular value decomposition which is used in the answers there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $A$ and $B$ have orthogonal graphs. It means that $(x, Ax)$ and $(y, By)$ are always orthogonal in $H\oplus H$, hence

$$0 = \langle x, y\rangle + \langle A x, B y\rangle
=\langle x, y\rangle + \langle B^*A x, y\rangle$$
It follows that
$$-B^*A = Id$$
So that $A$ is invertible and $B = - (A^{-1})^*$.

Comment: Okay, this answers the question but does not really help me with my original problem: There $U(\mathrm{Graph}(A))$ is the graph of an operator iff $A$ is invertible then it is the graph of $-A^{-1}$ so your answer provides that $A^*=-((-A^{-1})^{-1})^*$ which does not provide additional information on $A^*$.

Comment: Then may be I don't completely understand the question. Which exact property do you assume about $A$'s graph?