# Transpose of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

I have been trying to find an intuition for the transpose of a matrix. I have also read the posts in mathstackexhange but unfortunately it couldn’t help me.Can anyone please explain what is the idea behind the transpose of a matrix specially in linear algebra and operator theory?
Thanks for consideration.

Comment: It is the matrix for the linear map on the dual spaces, equipped with the dual bases. Didn't you see that somewhere?

Comment: This question here and its answers gives a geometric interpretation of the transpose: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37398/what-is-the-geometric-interpretation-of-the-transpose

Comment: You can arrange $n$-tuples of numbers either as row or column vectors, and we take $m$ of them.