# If $A^T=A$ then eigen vectors are orthogonal to each other

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

The statement is true, however I would like to know what does it mean geometrically. How do I check that the eigen vectors are orthogonal eigen vectors?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eigenvectors of real symmetric matrices are orthogonal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82467/eigenvectors-of-real-symmetric-matrices-are-orthogonal)

Comment: I am looking for a geometric reason @Rick

Comment: Eigenvectors beonging to *different* eigenvalues are orthogonal to each other (if $A^t=A$). Eigenvectors belonging to the same eigenvalue, even if linearly independent of each other, need not be orthogonal to each other.

Comment: The trouble with your question, smita, is that *orthogonality* is not a geometric concept. Sure, it's based on the geometric concept of a right angle in two- and three-dimensional Euclidean space, but outside of that context, in higher dimensions and in abstract vector spaces, there is no concept of right angles or of orthogonality beyond what we get from algebra, from defining an inner product and calling two vectors orthogonal if their inner product is zero. The eigenvector statement is purely algebraic; it has geometric content only by virtue of interpreting the algebra.

Comment: You may find some of the answers at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37398/what-is-the-geometric-interpretation-of-the-transpose helpful.